# Entity Framework Error 3002 / 3003 - Inheritance / key mapping issue

Tags: entity-framework

I have a data model as follows:

[image: Data Model]

A Customer has Products and Payment Methods. Each Product can be assigned any or all of the Customer's Payment Methods, with one set as default.

Foreign Keys are:

```
Customer.CustomerId => Product.CustomerId
Customer.CustomerId => PaymentMethod.CustomerId
Product.ProductId => ProductPaymentMethod.ProductId
PaymentMethod.PaymentMethodId => ProductPaymentMethod.PaymentMethodId
```

I want to customise this model for presentation purposes, Customer to have a collection of Payment Methods and a collection of Products. Products to have a collection of ProductPaymentMethods which inherit from PaymentMethod.

I deleted the association between PaymentMethod and ProductPaymentMethod, added an inheritence from PaymentMethod to ProductPaymentMethod and deleted PaymentMethodId from ProductPaymentMethod.

This is now my model:

[image: Presentation Model]

When I save the model or build the project I get 2 errors:

> Error 3002: Problem in mapping
>   fragments starting at line
>   226:Potential runtime violation of
>   table ProductPaymentMethod's keys
>   (ProductPaymentMethod.ProductPaymentMethodId):
>   Columns
>   (ProductPaymentMethod.ProductPaymentMethodId)
>   are mapped to EntitySet
>   PaymentMethods's properties
>   (PaymentMethods.ProductPaymentMethodId)
>   on the conceptual side but they do not
>   form the EntitySet's key properties
>   (PaymentMethods.PaymentMethodId).

and

> Error 3003: Problem in mapping
>   fragments starting at line 226:All the
>   key properties
>   (PaymentMethods.PaymentMethodId) of
>   the EntitySet PaymentMethods must be
>   mapped to all the key properties
>   (ProductPaymentMethod.ProductPaymentMethodId)
>   of table ProductPaymentMethod.

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT:** Having done some further Googling, I have found several solutions, most of which don't quite fit this scenario. Most talk about inheritance requiring a 1-1 not 1-many relationship. However, because of the Customer to Product 1-many relationship, the model requires a 1-many between PaymentMethod and ProfilePaymentMethod. Is it not possible to do what I am attempting?

Comment: Links or a summary of the near solutions you found would be nice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My only answer to this so far is to have some manually created POCO classes for presentation and a Mapper class to turn my data entity into a presentation entity